# Set delay before jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have this jQuery transition which displays a div in the centre of the page, then animates to the top.

Is it possible to set say, a 5 second delay before the div starts sliding up? Just enough time to read the text inside before the animation happens.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var tar = $('#loading');
    tar.fadeIn().animate({top: 0}, {duration: 1000, queue: false}, function() {
        //Animation complete.
    });
});
</script>
```

I can provide a link to the example dev site if it helps.

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you try the aptly-named [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) method?

Comment: I looked into that, but couldn't work out where to stick the code. I'm very inexperienced with jQuery if you could assist at all. Thanks.

Comment: `tar.fadeIn().animate({top: 0}, {delay: 5000, duration: 1000, queue: false}, function() {`

...Doing this doesn't seem to work

Comment: `delay()` is a method, you should call it between `fadeIn()` and `animate()` (and remove the `queue: false` option, otherwise the slide animation will not be queued and `delay()` will be useless).

Comment: In fact, it does, but stops the animation altogether. The delay is in place but the div simply appears in it's destination rather than origination where it should and then animating.

Comment: So, something like this?

`tar.fadeIn().delay(5000).animate({top: 0}, {duration: 1000, queue: false}, function() { `

Comment: Sorted it just now, thanks for the push in the right direction :-)